# Multilanguage Google TTS sentence

Tags: google-cloud-speech

I am experimenting with google cloud TTS service and i was wondering if multi language text synthesization is supported.

Specifically i am trying to synthesize a sentence containing Greek and English words. I tried slicing the sentence to single language only parts but the voices used for each language sound quite bit off, any known workaround?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want useful answers, you should always include details (the code as a minimum) of what you have tried and the outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.
Both **Google TTS** and **Amazon Polly** allow to mix different languages-voices in the same audio sequence (Multilingual audio stream).

Amazon goes a bit further with **some** truly bilingual voices.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/bilingual-voices.html

For Google TTS, you need to use SSML and you have examples here

https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/ssml#voice

---

In my experience, both (Google/Amazon) have 2 ways:

1. The native voice in language A tries to speak language B with 'some degree' of skill, but you can really feel the A-accent.
2. Switch voices, and speak each part with a native voice. In this way you do have 2 different voices, but each one speaks perfectly, all the in the same audio output.

(Python)

Example of 1: (google tts)

```
ssml_text = '''
<speak>Here is some English text.
<lang xml:lang="es-ES">Y nos dieron las diez y la una ...</lang></speak>
'''
```

Example of 2: (google tts)

```
ssml_text = '''
<speak>And there it was 

<voice name="en-GB-Wavenet-B">
a flying bird 
</voice>

<voice  name="es-ES-Wavenet-B">
Un chamaco muy revoltoso que no para de reirse.
</voice>

<voice  name="fr-FR-Wavenet-B">
Je ne parle pas français.
</voice>

</speak>
'''
```

---

Here you can practice a bit
https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech

But just a bit, because if your SSML text is too complex, it gets simplified (see in the picture upper vs lower text).

[image]

---

Luckily Google has extensive documentation and here you can find the code to practice/experiment.

https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/ssml-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with the Google cloud equivalent but they should also support [SSML](https://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis/#S3.1.2) (alternatively: [Amazon docs](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/speech-synthesis-markup-language-ssml-reference.html)). I would try to define a different language attribute **and** voice for the 'other' language part – if Google allows.

Please note: according to [this answer](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/speech-synthesis-markup-language-ssml-reference.html) it's recommended to have multiple language packs available and switch them accordingly.